# when i try to move the ik bone in the x axis the leg bone rotates suddenly

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, edit-mode, constraints

my problem is when i try to move the feet.ik in the x axis the leg bone rotates suddenly. i dont want to rotate the leg bone the way it is bending right now in the photo. Can someone help?
[image: the blue color bone is feet.ik it is the controller bone that is the parent of feet.L bone and the yellow bone is leg.L, the bone to which ik is being applied at. chain length is 2]

Comment: hello, maybe bend the knee a bit in Edit mode, or if it doesn't work share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots how do you know which file is uploaded by me ? just asking.

Comment: I can't, you need to share the link here  ;)

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/a2e3f78d9170494a839b0f712325a16b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your leg rotates because the IK is supposed to always bend towards its *Pole Target* and for the moment your *Pole Target* is pretty close to your knee, you just need to move your *Pole Target* a bit away in *Edit* mode and it will work fine. Also maybe bend the knee a bit forward in *Edit* mode:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, this solved my problem.

Comment: @AjaySharma Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, don't just reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).